# Stopped receiving firebase notifications completely suddenly

Tags: ios, swift

I am setting up iOS 12 push notifications for an application at work. They worked perfectly for the first 2 days, and then suddenly completely stopped. I have no access to the firebase server. I send an api key and device id via a post and the web app registers the device on the server. It worked perfectly for me the first time I set it up, and then suddenly it completely stopped working after that. It works perfectly on Android for some reason.

I've tried a lot of solutions and literally nothing worked, except NOT setting the apns token, when I don't set the apns token the firebase didrecievemessage gets called, but not the apple default one. IF I SET THE APNS TOKEN didReceive remoteMessage DOES NOT GET CALLED! I get no errors whatsoever. The code below was after many times, even checking out the version that worked before does nothing. The appcoord is the class that sets up my view controllers.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    appCoord.start()
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
        options: authOptions,
        completionHandler: {result,error  in print(result,error) })
    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    InstanceID.instanceID().deleteID{ error in
        Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .prod)
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true
    }
}

func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
    let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
    KeychainProvider.setToken(token: fcmToken)
    print(KeychainProvider.loadToken())
    appCoord.updateToken()
    Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "news")
    print("gottoken")
}

func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
    appCoord.updateInbox()
    print("msg",remoteMessage)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    print("dobio je notifikaciju")
    appCoord.updateInbox()
    Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    print("fjyfjdfj--------------------------------------")
    completionHandler()
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let notificationType = UIApplication.shared.currentUserNotificationSettings?.types
    print("push enabled")
    // custom code to handle push while app is in the foreground
    //            print("Handle push from foreground\(notification.request.content.userInfo)")

    let dict = notification.request.content.userInfo["aps"] as! NSDictionary
    let d : [String : Any] = dict["alert"] as! [String : Any]
    var body : String = d["body"] as! String
    let title : String = d["title"] as! String
    print("Title:\(title) + body:\(body)")
    completionHandler([.alert,.badge,.sound])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it worked previously and suddenly stopped, one specific case might be  if you are testing this on the same iOS device during development and production. It might stop working in development if it has received actual production notifications. If so, instead try it on an iOS device that hasn't been used for this app yet.